# COMExamplePlugIn in DMSDK requires running DM as Admin under Window 10, but not under Windows 7

Tags: sdk, dm-script

Using the Digital Micrograph SDK (DMSDK), I built (VS2017) and ran the example called COMExamplePlugIn under Windows 7 and it worked fine.  However, when I built and ran under Widows 10, the plug-in fails during the Run() call, reporting an error: "CoCreateInstance of COMExampleInterface failed (80004002)".  If I start Digital Micrograph as Administrator under Windows 10, the error goes away and the plug-in runs fine.  Also, the plug-in built under Windows 10 runs fine under Windows 7.
Has anyone else run into this issue?  How did you resolve it?  Running DM as Admin is not really an option for many users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is purely an OS issue. A standard user under Windows 10 no longer can make changes to the registry. In the COMExample a COM object gets registered on the fly, which requires changing the registry, and this is no longer possible, unless you’re an administrator.

You are right, that running GMS with elevated privileges is generally not recommended. Newer versions even give the following warning message in this case.

[image]

This example in the SDK should possibly be removed, as it is no longer a valid thing to do under Windows10. I am not aware of a suitable workaround for the issue. The only valid ways to register COM objects in Windows10 seem to be to use regsvr32 from a command prompt which is run at elevated privileges, or to do it from an application installer.